# Paste data from Excel to Word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have been searching this site and there appears to be numerous articles on `datatype:=wdpastetext`. However, I couldn't still find solution for issue that I have encountered with part of my code.

I'm copying data from excel to word `L19 to L38` as text. However, some of the rows from `L19` to `L38` are bold and underlined and I would like to retain that formatting. Code below is simply pasting it as normal text without bold or underline.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Range("L19:L38").Copy
With objWord
    .Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteText, _
     Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wdPasteText` is supposed to copy across just text. It doesn't copy across any formatting. `Bold` and `Underline` are part of formatting. If you want the formatting to be copied across then you can use `wdPasteHTML`.

```
With objWord
    .Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteHTML, _
    Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
End With
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

For other option see this KB article

[WdPasteDataType Enumeration (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197265.aspx)
[image]

Comment: Hi Sid, thank you so much for lightning fast response ONCE AGAIN. In fact, that is the first thing I tried. I did stumble across this link from msdn. Since, I wasn't sure, i tried all option in screenshot above, one by one. Problem I face is, unlike in your perfect screenshot, after macro is done pasting the data in word, I see blue dotted lines i.e a tabular format and it doesn't wrap up the text. Cell range that I'm trying to paste from excel has lot of text. After pasting to word, it doesn't wrap up the text; instead, pastes it as table (half visible text). See attached please.

Comment: I dont see anything attached?

Comment: Here's a screenshot link. Sorry, I couldn't find a way to attach it here through comments. https://prnt.sc/fhc58m

Comment: Strange. I do not get those lines.

Comment: Hi, apologies for delay in responding. Just came back from work. No worries. Possibly because I'm using excel 2007. I shall consider it as resolved. Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: Hi Siddhath, I mange to sort it by hit and trial. Posting few solutions that may work for other fellow users. Problem: Somehow, after running macro to paste excel cells to word, it was pasting it as a table (table1). Below solution helped me wrap up text, adjust table height and width, fit to window etc. Those blue lines in screenshot that I pasted above are simply print layout view (default in word 2007). It doesn't appear in print outs though. Print layout option is word 2007 is in view tab.

Comment: Also, you may want to check your word options and fiddle around with following: Word round button on top left > Word option > Advanced > Cut, Copy and paste section > Pasting from other program + check smart cut & paste + settings nexting to smart cut & paste (there are options here as well). Code that helped me wrap up my table 1 within A6 paper size and allowed me to define table height and width is as follows:

Comment: Range("L19:L38").Copy
With objWord
.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteHTML, Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False

With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
.PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
.PreferredWidth = 230
HeightRule = wdRowHeightAtLeast
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Height = 8
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.WrapAroundText = True
ActiveDocument.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0

End With

Useful:
.PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
.PreferredWidth = 230
.AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
HeightRule = wdRowHeightAuto

Comment: I would recommend posting it as an answer :)